# button on top of an image (but it's not staying put)

Tags: css, image, button, w3.css

Editing my original post ---

I had an image with text made as an image, with a button on the image that wouldn't stay put for responsive scrolling.

So I put up just the image, set the text to div. I have set my image to relative and text to absolute. ???? Now I cannot get my text div ON my jumbo image and I'm so stinking tired of this. (I also need a transparency behind my text but have given up on positioning that as well.)

HTML

```
<div class="w3-jumboimagecontainer> 
<div class="w3-display-container w3-jumboimage w3-center">
<img src="images/assistingelder.jpg" style="width:100%"></div>
<h5 class="ontop">
<h5 class="jumbonow">Now hiring</h5> <h5       
class="caregiversnow">Caregivers</h5> 
<h5 class="birminghamnow">in the Birmingham area</h5></h5>
<div class="w3-jumbotextsquare"">
<div class="w3-jumbobutton w3-button w3-xlarge w3-center">
<a href="caregiversapp.html" class="w3-button w3-xlarge">apply now! 
</a></div></div></div></div>
```

CSS

```
.w3-jumboimagecontainer {width: 100%;}
.w3-jumboimage {position: relative;}
h5.ontop {position: absolute;}
.w3-jumbobutton .w3-button {
background-color: #d7d78f;
border-color: #d7d78f;
color: #FFF; 
border-radius: 8px;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
object-position: center;
}
h5.jumbonow {font-family: "proxima-nova"; helvetica; arial; sans-   
serif;
font-weight: 200;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 50pt;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: white;
text-align: center;
top:0px;}
h5.caregiversnow {
font-family: georgia; serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-style: italic;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 60pt;
letter-spacing: 2px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
margin-top:px;}
h5.birminghamnow {font-family: "proxima-nova"; helvetica; arial;   
sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 30pt;
letter-spacing: 2px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
margin-top:px;}
```

Comment: This is a standard issue absolute positioning problem. Please take some time to grokk absolute, relative and fixed positioning. Ultimately you will want to take a different approach to your markup's structure. No reason to not use a background image and place the button inside an element with said background image.

Comment: I can def give that a go...thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it flies away, is that `left:630px;` is absolute. This means when the screen is smaller, the 630px won't be centered any more.

To solve this, use relative units. There are a lot of ways to center things in css and [howtocenterincss.com](http://howtocenterincss.com/) does a good job in giving you the css you want.

Alternatively `left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 0);` should work.

Note that the same is true for `bottom`, but here it might not be a problem.

---

However, since you also have text over your image, it would probably just be better to make the button position with that in mind.

Basically make a wrapper around both: the text and the button and align that wrapper in the middle of the image. Then just lay them out the way you want them to.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't bulletproof. What happens to the buttons location when the image shrinks? It'll likely overlay the text in the image.

Comment: @hungerstar not necessarily. His issue was only with the horizontal centering, so I figured he had no problem with vertical alignment. However, just `bottom: 225px;` will leave him with the same described problem, which is why I warned him about that.

Comment: @hungerstar maybe he wants to put the text outside of the image on smaller srceens, which would solve the overlaying issue. idk, but he only complained about the incorrect centering.

Comment: I cheated and the white text is part of the image. is that lazy design? :P I will try assigning it as a background image to the div.

Comment: Ideally and in the vast majority of instances, the text should not be included in images. It's bad SEO and creates accessibility issues. Best to avoid until you know when it's okay.

Comment: Yes, plus you have problems like this with scaleability. You cannot re-layout it for mobile, you cannot change the font-size (You probably won't be able to read it on mobile) You cannot copy it. You cannot translate and/or change it. You have to edit the picture every time. There are a lot of reasons (and some good articles on) why not to do that.